# How to write urls in mako python

Tags: python, mako

Hello there thanks for helping me,

I have some `file.mako.md` file and I am changing this file as shown below but it shows me 404 error which is due to it takes wrong url address ie it takes url like  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"` rather than `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` and due to which gives server error, any help will be appreciated

```py
<%!
  import requests
   
  def build_path_with_dataset_name(ds_name):
    github_path = "https://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/datasets/tree/patch-58/docs/catalog/images/" + ds_name + ".jpg"
    return github_path
  
  def example_exists(path):
    r = requests.head(path)
    return r.status_code == 302 
%>
```

it reads url `https://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/datasets/tree/patch-58/docs/catalog/images/"` gives 404 error [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIdAX.png)

EDIT : I think this is due to underline appear on can anybody know how can we remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with a f-string?

```
import requests

def build_path_with_dataset_name(ds_name):
    github_path = f"https://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/datasets/tree/patch-58/docs/catalog/images/{ds_name}.jpg"
    return github_path

def example_exists(path):
    r = requests.head(path)
    return r.is_redirect

dataset_name = 'mnist'
path = build_path_with_dataset_name(dataset_name)
print(example_exists(path))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I tried using f string, problem is when I see this .mako.md file there is underline below url which is problem

Comment: for f-string to work you need python 3.6.4 version and up. 
What error are you getting now?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is underline below url?"

Comment: Shows this error MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

Comment: I think it comes down to your check function actually, please have a look at my updated solution

Comment: Just tried you updated solution it works on colab or jupyter notebooks but gives me error when I was running my .mako.md file. Also without using fstrings it runs fine but gives error on .mako.md file , hope you understand this? It takes urls as `https://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/datasets/tree/patch-58/docs/catalog/images/%7Bds_name%7D.jpg"` why it takes " in last

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solves my problem also thanks to @pierresegonne for give time on it,

Problem is `.md` files takes "http://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/" as automatic url due to which it also include last quote `"` here is solution to this.

```py
import requests

def dataset_examples_paths(ds_name):
 github_path = "http://" + "github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/datasets/tree/patch-60/docs/catalog/images/" + ds_name + ".jpg"
 return github_path

def example_exists(path):
 r = requests.get(path)
 return r.status_code==200

dataset_name = 'mnist'
path = build_path_with_dataset_name(dataset_name)
print(example_exists(path))
```